# Automatically adjusting font size to fit container

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-size, adjustment

I have a defined style for `div` with fixed width and the text inside the `div` could have different lengths, like in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/haynar/3HxgM/1/). Is there any method using CSS and/or JS to adjust the text size in such a way that it will stay in bounds of the container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this may work for you, try this

```
var originalFontSize = 12;

var divWidth = $('.cell').width();

$('.cell span').each(function(){

    var spanWidth = $(this).width();

    var newFontSize = (divWidth/spanWidth) * originalFontSize;

    $(this).css({"font-size" : newFontSize, "line-height" : newFontSize/1.2 + "px"});

});​
```

Comment: Was about to post something similar, but your solution is more efficient. The downside is though that there is no threshold and the `veeeeeery looooooong text` becomes illegible.